# Different DNS query results from different locations

Tags: domain-name-system

I get different results on querying the same DNS server from different locatoins. E.g. from home:

```
> nslookup en.wikipedia.org 8.8.8.8
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    en.wikipedia.org
Address:  198.35.26.96
```

From DigitalOcean's VPS:

```
$ nslookup en.wikipedia.org 8.8.8.8
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   en.wikipedia.org
Address: 208.80.154.224
```

From another location in another country:

```
> nslookup en.wikipedia.org 8.8.8.8
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    en.wikipedia.org
Address:  91.198.174.192
```

How is this possible? I get the same results upon querying the SOA (`ns0.wikimedia.org` at `208.80.154.238`) instead of Google's server as well. I would assume some kind of round-robin, but no! Returned IP is always the same for the same location. And all returned IPs belong to WikiMedia according to reverse DNS records, so this is not some kind of malware. But how does it work then?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/faq#anycast -- in first hit googling 'google DNS regional' also linked from second para of Wikpedia Google_Public_DNS .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's GeoDNS, or whatever people like to call it. There are some providers that offer this service. Different results based on where the lookup came from.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodns

https://www.zerigo.com/docs/managed-dns/setting_up_geodns

https://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/#what_is_geo_dns

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because it's using the DNS server IP address with the shortest amount of hops from the location your doing the lookup from.  If you check all the addresses from arin.net (the one's that aren't RIPE) they are owned by `WIKIMEDIA`.

I did an `NSLOOKUP` with `LSERVER` from Germany and got the same `91.198.174.192` as you did. I did from my US location and got the same `208.80.154.224` as you did.

I don't think you're at risk for malware based on my results that matches what you got.

Comment: I've never heard of such feature. Is it documented somewhere? How do you configure a DNS server to behave this way? How does `8.8.8.8` repeat this behavior?